# Octave algorithm loop iteration

Tags: for-loop, octave, break

Can someone please tell me why this Octave algorithm does not execute the last iteration where i = 4 and j = 2? It seems to be affected by the break condition in the inner for-loop but this should not affect the last iteration.

```
x = [2, 3, 4];
h = [1, 2];
y = [0, 0, 0, 0];

for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:2
        printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
        if((i-j < 0) || (i-j > 2)) break; endif
        y(i) = y(i) + h(j) * x(i-j+1);
    endfor
endfor
```

I've tested it on my Debian system and it stops at i = 4 and j = 1. The output is:

```
i = 1, j = 1
i = 1, j = 2
i = 2, j = 1
i = 2, j = 2
i = 3, j = 1
i = 3, j = 2
i = 4, j = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:2
        if ((0 <= i-j) && (i-j <= 2))
            printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
            y(i) = y(i) + h(j) * x(i-j+1);
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

or

```
for i = 1:4
    for j = 1:2
        if ((i-j < 0) || (i-j > 2)) continue; endif
        y(i) = y(i) + h(j) * x(i-j+1);
        printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    endfor
endfor
```

In your code, when i==4 and j==1 the statement

```
if((i-j < 0) || (i-j > 2)) break; endif
```

will jumps out of the innermost for loop. The outermost for loop is already completed (i==4) and the programs ends.

References:

- [continue](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-continue-Statement.html) statement
- [break](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-break-Statement.html) statement

Comment: This answer is very clear and helpful. Great job and +1 for the alternative ways of doing it. Hats off to you sir! Unfortunately I don't have enough points to vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you call "break", this is equally to jumping after the "endfor". So for i=4, j=1 (i-j) gets 3, you call "break" and i=4, j=2 never runs. See "continue" because I think this is what you want.

Comment: Ah, excellent! I was indeed intending to execute the continue statement. I guess I got fooled by it working for the case i=1, j=2 (where i-j = -1) simply because it was at the end of an inner for-loop iteration. Thanks, a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your script in javascript. Here I have outputted the results of your condition. Seems like the scripts you have written performs as intended.

```
x = [2, 3, 4];
h = [1, 2];
y = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for(i=1; i<5;i++) {
 for(j=1;j<3;j++) {
   console.log('i'+i+" j"+j);
   console.log('i -j > 2 '+(i -j > 2));
   console.log('i-j < 0 '+(i-j < 0));
   if((i-j < 0) || (i -j > 2)) { break;}
   y[i] = y[i] + h[j] * x[i-j+1];
 }
}
```

execute it in your chrome console to validate your the cases.

Comment: Yes, i intended to use the continue statement rather than break. Thanks for checking though!